# create PHP search using tags

Tags: php, html, search, if-statement, tags

How can I build a search using php.
I want to tag the pages like this:

```
<meta name="tag" content="plant, leaf, waterdroplet, water" />
```

and I would like to search and have it bring up a link to the pages that are tagged with the tag you have searched.

This is what Iv'e tried but I doen't work and it's not exactly what I want.

## search.php

```
<form id="searchImput" action="search.php" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="input" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
    $input = $_GET["input"];

$tags = get_meta_tags('http://s0ulp1xel.x10.mx/background-garage/?p=photo&photo=1');
$tags = array_map('trim', explode(',', $tags['tag']));
foreach($tags as $k => $v) {


if ($input == 'water')
{

 echo '<a href="/background-garage/?p=photo&photo=4">'. $v. '</a><br/>';
}
}
?>
```

## image.php

```
<head>
<meta id="pageType" name="photo">
<img name="1.png" id="photo" src="/background-garage/fullphoto/id/1.png?<?php echo Time () ?>"/>
<meta name="tag" content="plant, leaf, waterdroplet, water" />
</head>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Does it give you an error? A blank screen? The wrong content? (And should `if ($imput == 'water')` be `$input`?)

Comment: @andrewsi it always shows the result even if I type in "test" it still show the link to the other page

Comment: @s0ulp1xel - add some debugging and make sure that you're getting the tags correctly, and that the values you're comparing are the values you think you're comparing

Comment: @andrewsi here is a live preview: [link](http://s0ulp1xel.x10.mx/background-garage/search.php)

Comment: @s0ulp1xel - it doesn't seem to be printing any debugging information.

Comment: @andrewsi now it always prints "plantleafwaterdropletwater".

Comment: I can't see the PHP code, so I have no idea what that's from. On the other hand, it's no longer printing out the link.

Comment: @andrewsi I updated my original post with the current PHP code.

Comment: Have you fixed the typo with `$imput`? And why is that hardwired to look for "water"?

Comment: @andrewsi I just fixed the typo.

Comment: Change the line to `if ($input == $v)`, and see if that helps?

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks! that really helped, but how can I have it print no results when the tag isn't found?

Comment: @s0ulp1xel - You need to create a flag to count the number of matched files; increment that every time you print out a link. If it's still 0 at the end of the loop, print out a message saying "No results found"

Comment: @fonini - well spotted; you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if ($input == $v)` 
instead of 
`if ($input == 'water')`